# Regularity in $0$ of the inverse of a convex function $C^2(\mathbb{R})$ and such that $\lim\limits_{|x|\rightarrow +\infty}u(x)=+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, inverse

Let $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a convex and $C^2(\mathbb{R})$ function such that $\lim\limits_{|x|\rightarrow +\infty}u(x)=+\infty$ and $u(0)=0=\min_{\mathbb{R}}u$.

Now I know that I can consider the inverse functions of the restrictions of $u$ for positive and negative $x$:

if $u_+:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow[0,+\infty)$, $u_+(x)=u(x)$ for every $x\geq 0$ then exist the inverse function of $u_+$, i.e. $(u_+)^{-1}$;

if $u_-:(-\infty,0]\rightarrow[0,+\infty)$, $u_-(x)=u(x)$ for every $x\leq 0$ then exist the inverse function of $u_-$, i.e. $(u_-)^{-1}$.

I denote \begin{equation*} 
\phi(y)=\begin{cases}( u_+)^{-1}(y)\quad y\geq 0 \;\\ (u_-)^{-1}(y) \quad y\leq 0.\end{cases} 
\end{equation*}

> I would like to prove that the function $y\rightarrow\phi(y)\;$  is  $\;C^1(\mathbb{R})$.

**Edit**
I have proved that $\phi$ is $C^0(\mathbb{R})$ and that it is derivable in $(0,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$.
The only problem is the derivability in $y=0$.

How can I prove that $$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^+}\phi'(y)=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^-}\phi'(y)?$$

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Clearly you are assuming that $0$ is a strict minimum point. Try to compute $\phi$ in the case $u(x) = x^2$.